# What is the regular expression for Date format dd\mm\yyyy?

Tags: java, regex

What is the regular expression for Date format dd\mm\yyyy? I am unable to find out regex for this format?

Comment: Use the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386520/parse-date-from-string-in-this-format-dd-mm-yyyy-to-dd-mm-yyyy and changed the slashes (/) to double backslashes (\\\)

Comment: @AlexTaylor Thanks for quick reply, I am looking for regular exp for above date format, can you please tell me that?

Comment: Do you really want a date format with backslashes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion, it's best to verify the formatting using a regular expression, but verify the validity with code (Java, in your case).  It would be absurdly verbose to try to check things like differing days per month and leap years with a regular expression.

I suggest parsing the date using a regex like `([0-9]{2})\\([0-9]{2})\\([0-9]{4})`, then extract each piece (`dd`, `mm`, and `yyyy`, respectively), and try to create a `java.util.Date` object out of them.

Note the following:

- Dates are typically written with forward slashes (`/`) not backslashes (`\`),
- In Java strings, to write a backslash character in a regular expression, you will have to actually write `\\\\` for two backslash (`\\`) characters. In java strings to write a backslash we need the escape character (which is again a `\`).

Comment: +1 Shouldn't it be `([0-9]{2})\\\\([0-9]{2})\\\\([0-9]{4})` ?

Comment: Yes, it should, in a Java string.  The regular expression above is kind of the generic regex, but if using a Java string, four slashes need to be used (see note **(b)** at the end of my answer).

Comment: With this regex you end up accepting invalid date, like "99\99\9999"

Answer (score 10):

regex for  pattern  dd/mm/yyyy

```
    String regex = "^([0-2][0-9]||3[0-1])/(0[0-9]||1[0-2])/([0-9][0-9])?[0-9][0-9]$";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        /**
         * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
         * User: S34N
         * Date: 2013/07/30
         * Time: 8:21 AM
         * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
         */



        //Import the required classes/packages
        import javax.swing.*;
        import java.text.DateFormat;
        import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
        import java.util.Date;

        public class dateInputScan {

            public static void main(String args[]) {

                dateInputScan run = new dateInputScan();
                run.dateInputScan();
            }

            public void dateInputScan() {

                //Instantiating variables
                String lvarStrDateOfTransaction = null;
                DateFormat formatter = null;
                Date lvarObjDateOfTransaction = null;

                //Use one of the following date formats.
                lvarStrDateOfTransaction = "29/07/2013";
                //lvarStrDateOfTransaction = "29-07-2013";
                //lvarStrDateOfTransaction = "20130729";
                //lvarStrDateOfTransaction = "2013-07-29";
                //lvarStrDateOfTransaction = "29/07/2013";

                //You can also add your own regex (Regular Expression)
                if (lvarStrDateOfTransaction.matches("([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})")) {
                    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                } else if (lvarStrDateOfTransaction.matches("([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})")) {
                    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                } else if (lvarStrDateOfTransaction.matches("([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})")) {
                    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                } else if (lvarStrDateOfTransaction.matches("([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})")) {
                    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                } else if (lvarStrDateOfTransaction.matches("([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})")) {
                    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                }

                try {
                    lvarObjDateOfTransaction = formatter.parse(lvarStrDateOfTransaction);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Date: " + lvarObjDateOfTransaction);

                } catch (Exception ex) {    //Catch the Exception in case the format is not found.
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this `^[0-3]{1}[0-9]{1}/[0-1]{1}[1-2]{1}/[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3}$` and it works

```
String dateRegEx="^[0-3]{1}[0-9]{1}/[0-1]{1}[1-2]{1}/[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3}$";
System.out.println(Pattern.matches(dateRegEx, "01/01/1990"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`([0-2][0-9]||3[0-1])\\(0[0-9]||1[0-2])\\((19|20)\d\d)`

Above regex will validate
1st 2 character in between range of  0-31 
then next group must contain character in between range 0-12
then next group contain year in between range 1900-2099

It is working perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 1):

I have done this one for format DDMMYY

```
([0-2]?[0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(0?0[1-9]|1[0-2])([0-9][0-9])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna fixed version use:

```
  private static final String FIXED_DATE_PATTERN = 
      "(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/((19|20)\\d\\d)";
```

This force zero in days, and month values, and dont allow inputs like 00/12/2018 or 07/00/2018 in DD/MM/YYYY

Answer (score 0):

for "dd/MM/yyyy" You can use :

```
(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]|[1-9])/(0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9])/([0-9]{4})
```

- Day (dd): it accept 1 or 01, 9 or 09 (until 31)
- Month (MM): it accept 1 or 01 (until 12)
- Year (yyyy): It accept 4 digit