# Java SimpleDateFormat use pattern with jolly character

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Is there a way to parse a date with a pattern containing some "special char" or "jolly char" as separator with standard SimpleDateFormat?  I want to parse my date using the patterns `"yyyy MM dd"`, `"yyyy/MM/dd"`, `"yyyy-MM-dd"` and so on..., so I'm searching something like "yyyy*MM*dd" where * is a special character meanings 'a random character'

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date d = fmt.parse(stringdate);
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678681/how-to-compare-to-string-date-formates-in-java/41695780#41695780) could help you, because it solves the problem of parsing a date string by a set of possible input formats.

Comment: My time library Time4J can be used for this purpose in a very performant way, see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/MenoData/7cfe852a62f80f32b914009dc366dc5e), also possible on Java-6-platform with a slightly different syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a RegEx to filter out the funny characters, then parse the filtered string?

```
String stringdate = "2017x01-18"; 
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date d = fmt.parse(Pattern.compile("(....).(..).(..)").matcher(stringdate).replaceAll("$1-$2-$3"));
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try this

```
 String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

    String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
    System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to 'normalize' your input to desired format:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
fmt.parse(stringdate.replaceAll(" ", "-").replaceAll("/","-"));
```