# Take date as input and read month and day

Tags: java, date

so i need to take an input from User in the format of "MM/DD/YYYY"
and later read the day and month from the user input to use in some other calculations 
i tried using strings and Gregorian calendar but i have no idea how to do that

Comment: show your code and then we can go on from there.

Comment: i tried writing some but didn't go anywhere

Comment: i'm talking input in a string is there any way to parse to use it in calendar

Comment: Hint: `java.time.MonthDay.from( LocalDate.parse( … , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( … ) ) )`

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
cal.setTime(dateFormat.parse("12/23/2017"));
```

Now you can get all kind of metrics form the calendar easily.

Comment: If you can, do yourself the favour of skipping the old classes `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` and using the new classes `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` introduced in Java 8. See [this answer to the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43301263/5772882).